# Big distortion when scaling illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, resize

i read a lot of a threads on this web but still i can't find a solution for my problem. I saw a similar problem thread but it didn't fix it for me.

SO when i want to scale my created logo I always get unevenly scaled or distorted vectors.
I turned off snap to pixel grid,even with the shape selected.
I also have checked transform both and scale strokes and effects.
and still end up with this.
any suggestions?
the first image is before scaling and second after scaling to smaller size.
Everything is path not stroke
[image: Before scaling]

[image: afterscaling]

Comment: Could you upload a screenshot in outline mode? (CMD+Y)

Comment: Are those shapes in a group? If not, you could try grouping them and transform the entire group. Else try to join the paths as much as you can, maybe create compound paths. If you just want a smaller raster version of your logo you can change the size on export btw, there's no need to scale the vector artwork.

Comment: How are you doing the scaling?

Answer (score 0):

So i finally find the problem, i got hint in the outline mode.
The problem was that i had to join the paths together to make the scaling.
so in the pathfinder-merge option.
this is how it looked
[image]

and this is after
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem.  Crazy distortion on just this one file (a logo) where the grouped shapes distorted and moved if I tried to re-size the logo. I finally found THIS to work: Select the multiple group shapes. Choose Pathfinder. Shape Mode. Unite.  For some odd reason, that was my solution. Everything sizes and resizes as it should now.